# Data driven testing in cucumber feature file using external source like CSV or EXCEL

Tags: testing, cucumber

I have created cucumber feature file. As of now I am giving input from scenario outline with Examples.

But My test data is very huge now. I just want to give input from CSV or EXCEL.

Could you please explain How to achieve this ?

Comment: Your test open CSV or EXCEL file or is it your data of tests come from CSV or EXCEL file?

Comment: I am just supplying test data to feature file from .CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

[NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) (NOn-Regression Automation for User Interfaces, is a Java framework based on Selenium, Cucumber and Gherkin stack to create GUI testing projects that can be included in the continuous integration chain of single/multi applications web solution builds) does exactly that in his code:

https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/main/ScenarioInitiator.java

All lines are replace betwin `#DATA` and `#END` (without the header).

In your feature file:

```
@hello 
Feature: hello (Function to validate the environment.) 

  Scenario Outline: Function to validate the environment.

    Given ...
    And I go back to 'DEMO_HOME'        

  Examples:
    #DATA
    |id|author|zip|city|element|element2|date|title|
    |1|Jenkins T1|35000|Rennes|smile|smile|16/01/2020||
    |2|Jenkins T2|75000|Paris|smile|smile|||
    |3|Jenkins T3|56100|Lorient|smile|smile|||
    |4|Jenkins T4|35000|Rennes|smile|smile|||
    #END
```

full source [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/test/resources/steps/hello.feature).